# Cisco 678 Will Not Work using PPPoE

Tags: cisco, modem, adsl, dsl, pppoa

I am attempting to configure a Cisco 678 because I am totally sick on my Actiontec. However, I am running into some problems. It seems as though the Cisco is able to train the line, but I am unable to ping out.

It is almost like I am not correctly configuring the device to grab it's IP using PPPoA (like my Actiontec.) The output from "show running" (below) makes me think this too.

Below are the commands I ran in order to configure this:

```
# en
# set nvram erase
# write
# reboot
# en
# set nat enable
# set dhcp server enable
# set PPP wan0-0 ipcp 0.0.0.0
# set ppp wan0-0 dns 0.0.0.0
# set PPP wan0-0 login xxxxx // My actual login
# set PPP wan0-0 password yyyyy // My actual password
# set PPP restart enabled
# set int wan0-0 close
# set int wan0-0 vpi 0
# set int wan0-0 vci 32
# set int wan0-0 open
# write
# reboot
```

Here is the output from a few commands I thought could provide some useful information:

```
cbos#ping 74.125.224.113
Sending 1 8 byte ping(s) to 74.125.224.113 every 2 second(s)
Request timed out

cbos#show version

Cisco Broadband Operating System
CBOS (tm) 678 Software (C678-I-M), Version v2.4.9 - Release Software
Copyright (c) 1986-2001 by cisco Systems, Inc.
Compiled Nov 17 2004 15:26:29
DMT FULL firmware version G96
NVRAM image at 0x1030f000

cbos#show errors
- Current Error Messages -
## Ticks        Module     Level      Message
 0 000:00:00:00 PPP        Info       IPCP Open Event on wan0-0
 1 000:00:00:14 ATM        Info       Wan0 Up
 2 000:00:00:14 PPP        Info       PPP Up Event on wan0-0
 3 000:00:01:54 PPP        Info       PPP Down Event on wan0-0
Total Number of Error Messages: 4

cbos#show interface wan0
wan0   ADSL Physical Port
       Line Trained
Actual Configuration:
  Overhead Framing:           3
  Trellis Coding:             Enabled
  Standard Compliance:        T1.413
  Downstream Data Rate:       1184 Kbps
  Upstream Data Rate:         928 Kbps
  Interleave S Downstream:    4
  Interleave D Downstream:    16
  Interleave R Downstream:    16
  Interleave S Upstream:      4
  Interleave D Upstream:      8
  Interleave R Upstream:      16
  Modem Microcode:            G96
  DSP version:                0
  Operating State:            Showtime/Data Mode
Configured:
  Echo Cancellation:          Disabled
  Overhead Framing:           3
  Coding Gain:                Auto
  TX Power Attenuation:       0dB
  Trellis Coding:             Enabled
  Bit Swapping:               Disabled
  Standard Compliance:        T1.413
  Remote Standard Compliance: T1.413
  Tx Start Bin:               0x6
  Tx End Bin:                 0x1f
  Data Interface:             Utopia L1
Status:
  Local SNR Margin:           19.0dB
  Local Coding Gain:          7.5dB
  Local Transmit Power:       12.5dB
  Local Attenuation:          46.0dB
  Remote Attenuation:         31.0dB
Local Counters:
  Interleaved RS Corrected Bytes:         0
  Interleaved Symbols with CRC Errors:    2
  No Cell Delineation Interleaved:        0
  Out of Cell Delineation Interleaved:    0
  Header Error Check Counter Interleaved: 0
  Count of Severely Errored Frames:       0
  Count of Loss of Signal Frames:         0
Remote Counters:
  Interleaved RS Corrected Bytes:         0
  Interleaved Symbols with CRC Errors:    1
  No Cell Delineation Interleaved:        0
  Header Error Check Counter Interleaved: 0
  Count of Severely Errored Frames:       0
  Count of Loss of Signal Frames:         0

cbos#show int wan0-0
WAN0-0  ATM Logical Port
        PVC (VPI 0, VCI 32) is configured.
        ScalaRate set to Auto
        AAL 5         UBR Traffic
        IP Port Enabled

cbos#show running
Warning: traffic may pause while NVRAM is being accessed
[[ CBOS = Section Start ]]
NSOS MD5 Enable Password = XXXX
NSOS MD5 Root Password = XXXX
NSOS MD5 Commander Password = XXXX
[[ PPP Device Driver = Section Start ]]
PPP Port User Name = 00, "XXXX"
PPP Port User Password = 00, XXXX
PPP Port Option = 00, IPCP,IP Address,3,Auto,Negotiation Not Required,Negotiable
,IP,0.0.0.0
PPP Port Option = 00, IPCP,Primary DNS Server,129,Auto,Negotiation Not Required,
Negotiable,IP,0.0.0.0
PPP Port Option = 00, IPCP,Secondary DNS Server,131,Auto,Negotiation Not Require
d,Negotiable,IP,0.0.0.0
[[ ATM WAN Device Driver = Section Start ]]
ATM WAN Virtual Connection Parms = 00, 0, 32, 0
[[ DHCP = Section Start ]]
DHCP Server = enabled
[[ IP Routing = Section Start ]]
IP NAT = enabled
[[ WEB = Section Start ]]
WEB = enabled

cbos# wtf...?
```

Comment: 'set bridging rfc1483 disabled' / 'write' / 'reboot' also does not help.